# AWS S3 PreSigned URL Permissions at the Creation Level & Usage Level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Is there a way to restrict the permissions of my Users so that, they should not be able to create/generate a presigned URL for the S3 objects that they have access to. ?? My users should not be able to generate a pre-signed URL even if they have access to the S3 objects.

Either restricting their ability of generating presigned URL or atleast detecting an action in real-time when its created is also fine with me.

It looks like there is no cloudtrail API call for generating presigned URL or also there is no cloudtrail API call whenever the generated presigned URL is used for accessing the S3 object.

So, I am stuck at this point and we as a platform team need to stop our App users from being able to generate presigned URLs and give them out to unauthorized users.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither restricting the ability to generate presigned URL nor the usage detection is currently possible. From the S3 server's perspective, a request using presigned URL is no different from a normal request generated by the CLI or SDK for example.